# Handling special characters in json_encode

Tags: php, json

In my database, there are many special characters like (İstanbul, Yeşilköy, Atatürk and more).

when I directly fetch these data from the database all working fine. Means data remain original but problem occur when I convert these data to JSON using json_encode().

After encoding all these data converted to some strange characters like
 ?stanbul, Bak?rköy...

But after decodeing (using json_decode) I need the original string which was before encoding(json_encode).

I tried many solutions provided on the web to solve the problem but none of them is fully working in my case.

some solutions I tried-

- $item =   utf8_encode($item);
- $item = html_entity_decode($item, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
- I also tried a library available on github (https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8)

If not possible to get the original string atleast there should not be any ? like thing(remove these things).

Suggest me something to solve the issue.

Comment: // set charset in your mysql query
**mysqli_query($conn, "SET CHARSET utf8")**

Comment: I am setting header to header('Content-Type: application/json charset=utf-8'); and my data is fine after getting from database but changed after encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library saved my life(https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8).

Previously I was using the wrong method to get the issue resolved.
**toUTF8()** function was life saver.

Answer (score 8):

Since PHP 5.4 you can use this :

```
json_encode($text, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: Work like a charm! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Use *mysqli_set_charset(connection,charset);* before *mysqli_query();*

**Example:**

```
mysqli_set_charset( $CONNECTION, "utf8" );

$result_query = mysqli_query( $CONNECTION, $query );
```